# MacBook Pro Recovery Mode Broken

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, partition, recovery

A few weeks ago I installed Linux Fedora on my MacBook Pro (Late 2011) and wanted to switch back to macOS now, but I have experienced a lot of problems.

Latest Internet Recovery: For some reason, I can’t do an internet recovery with the latest version (High Sierra). My error log can be viewed [here](https://pastebin.com/TufRSygP).

I think it’s because I don’t have enough disk space, but I have enough. It’s failing downloading the catalog. Maybe Fedora destroyed one partition of the recovery system?

macOS Lion Recovery Mode: Can’t download the OS X version Lion, because the certs of Apple expired way back. Changing the date didn't help.

I tried to create a bootable usb stick with TransMac, but it doesn’t show up in the Startup Manager.

Comment: When using High Sierra Internet Recovery, did you first use the Disk Utility to erase the drive before installing High Sierra?